# C Output Return Value

Tags: c++, c

```
int fun(int a) {
    if((a=10) && (a==20))
        pritnf("Good question\t.");
    (a>=20)?return(10):return(20);
}
int main() {
    int i = fun(20);
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Why is this giving compile error?

Comment: `if( (a=10) && (a==20) )` Maybe not a compiler error, but what...?

Comment: Have you considered writing more readable code? And by the way, my libtelepathy.so needs to be upgraded, so would you mind telling what was the compiler's output?

Comment: @uts:  I fixed the indenting for you. Next time on, please indent your code before posting here.

Comment: Also, `return a >= 20 ? 10 : 20;`

Answer (score 7):

You want `return a >= 20 ? 10 : 20`. `return` is a statement, and therefore can't be part of an expression.

Comment: Correct solution, but with no explanation of the problem (that `return` is a statement, and can't be part of an expression.

Answer (score 5):

For one `printf` is is misspelled as `pritnf` in:

```
pritnf("Good question\t.");
```

It would be *really* helpful if you could post the exact compiler error message with the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (a=10) && (a==20) )
```

should be

```
 if( (a==10) && (a==20) )
```

this kinda does not make sense did you mean or ?

and you are missing the return

Comment: That won't produce a compile error - it's valid C. Although probably not what was meant, I agree - but even corrected it doesn't make sense because a will not equal both 10 and 20 at the same time.

Comment: that's why i thought it was ment 10 or 20  statment